# Why am I getting 405 errors after swappinng domain names?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, php5

I had oldsubdomain.xxx.com.  Everything was working fine.  Windows 2008 R2 IIS 7.5 running php sites.  Also had SSL running and used for all sites.

So I needed to change to newsubdomain.xxx.com.  Installed new cert and edited bindings... New subdomain is working.  Kind of.  When people try to login to our apps via SSO they are getting "405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed" after the SSO delivers their info.

Also oldsubdomain.xxx.com is now set up as an alias by our network team.  It redirects to newsubdomain.xxx.com in your browser but gives the same "405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed".  If you refresh the page is loads fine...

I checked the php handler and it is allowing all verbs.  Where do I start troubleshooting this?  As far as I know no other changes were made to the web server.

```
Module  DefaultDocumentModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler StaticFile
Error Code  0x80070001
```

Comment: What does the client use after SSO? Looks like the client is doing a POST-request on what IIS considers a static file. Is the handler for php missing? Or maybe a default-document (index.php/default.php).

Comment: @lsmooth - The SSO signs the user in and sends a POST-request back to our server.  POST is on for PHP and I have about 5 Wordpress sites and other PHP sites running just fine.  I have index.php set as my default doc everywhere... really lost.  I take the post and set usernames for sites based on this.  Same exact process works just fine on server sitting right next to it that is IIS 6 W2003.

Comment: But the php handler is setup correct?

Answer (score 1):

This may be the result of how your URL is formatted, I ran into a similar issue with a WordPress theme that had a preview function that didn't work on IIS 7.5.

The reasoning is explained here: http://forums.iis.net/post/1912220.aspx

Essentially, the issue was that the URL didn't have a trailing / at the end of the path which causes some conflicts with the default document when posting to it (more or less, the link above explains it better)

Example:

```
http://localhost/wp_site?preview=true&_wpnonce=a1ef3f4811
```

VS

```
http://localhost/wp_site/?preview=true&_wpnonce=a1ef3f4811
```

The second URL works perfectly whereas the first one throws up a 405 error

Comment: I voted this up but not mark it correct as it was a bug with 7.5 but not the one in your answer.  Also to make matters worse MS fix for the bug didn't work at all so we had to redo all of our SSO scripts to have a "/".  This exact script was up working great in IIS 6... After 5 hours of troubleshooting and talking with MS, their rep said you might want to redo the script.

Comment: Ouch - that's unfortunate but is probably what I would've expected from MS - IIS has always been a strange beast IMO.  Hopefully our respective pains will save others a similar fate.